# How do I set different font sizes for different screens sizes that updates dynamically in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I couldn't find anything about this in Ionic 3's CSS Utilities under Responsive Text Attribute section.

I learnt that we can center align text by targeting specific screen sizes:

```
<div [attr.text-center]="isMD ? '' : null">I will be centered when isMD is true.</div>
```

But we can't use the `isMD` with `ngClass` as for some reason`isMD evaluates to true` whatever the screen size.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'font-lg': isMD}">I'm visible on all screens.</div>
```

We also have `Platform` available in our Ionic app so I could do things like

I tried:

```
screenIsSM: boolean = this.platform.width() <= 576;
screenIsMD: boolean = this.platform.width() > 576 && this.platform.width() <= 768;
screenIsLG: boolean =  this.platform.width() > 768 && this.platform.width() <= 992;
screenIsXL: boolean = this.platform.width() > 992 && this.platform.width() <= 1200;
```

and tried to used it as:

```
<span [ngClass]="{
    'font-sm' : screenIsSM,
    'font-md' : screenIsMD,
    'font-lg' : screenIsLG,
    'font-xl' : screenIsXL
}">Test</span>
```

Nothing happens for some reason. However, If I do

```
{{ screenIsSM ? 'SMALL SCREEN' : 'BIGGER SCREENS' }}
```

It does give me the desired result but this seems to work only once when the page loads and does not respond to dynamic change in screen size. What's the correct approach?

Comment: Wouldn't your screen size never change on a device? Screen size should be constant.

Comment: I understand that's usually the case but I'm building a PC app using Ionic that should look readable in all resolutions and devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the resize event, so in your Constructor:

```
constructor(
    ngZone: NgZone
) {
    window.onresize = (e) =>
    {
        ngZone.run(() => {
            this.resize();
        });
    };
}

resize() {
    screenIsSM: boolean = this.platform.width() <= 576;
    screenIsMD: boolean = this.platform.width() > 576 && this.platform.width() <= 768;
    screenIsLG: boolean =  this.platform.width() > 768 && this.platform.width() <= 992;
    screenIsXL: boolean = this.platform.width() > 992 && this.platform.width() <= 1200;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it should work but it doesn't. The font displays the same whatever the screen size. No class is applied.

Comment: instead of platform.width try using the window.width from native JS